# How to call old intent when app starts with sharing?

Tags: c#, android, pdf, xamarin.forms

I want to explain my app logic. My app is viewing PDFs. There are 2 ways to show pdfs.

1. The user logins the app and clicks the Show PDF button. Then, App opens a new window and the user selects a pdf for see it.
2. The user opens a pdf from his phone storage and shares that pdf to my application. (If the user didn't login to the app before, App opens the login page.)

The first one works fine. But when the user shares a pdf to my app from his phone storage, Application opens my HomePape Automatically.

There are 2 public LoginPage(){} in the app.

1.public LoginPage()

2.public LoginPage(string _pdfUri)

The first one lets user login the app.
The second one if user didn't login the app and shares a pdf to the app. In this way, the app gets pdfpath and opens the PdfShowPage.

Lets check the code,

App.xaml.cs:

/* I debugged this. App always comes here even when The user shares Pdf. Because of this,
PdfShowPage LoginPage works and LoginPage(string _pdfUri) does not work. The app opens HomePage.
Basicly;

LoginPage()  -> HomePage

LoginPage(string _pdfUri) -> PdfShowPage

*/

```
 public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
                MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage())
                {
                    BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("008000"),
                    BarTextColor = Color.FromHex("E8E8E8")
                };            
        }

protected override void OnStart()
        {
           // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
```

MainActivity.cs,

```
protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.Platform.Init();
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());

            Share();           

        }

private void Share()
{
   //Some codes for share
   Navigate(path);
}

public async void Navigate(string path)
{
            await Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new LoginPage(path));

}
```

LoginPage.cs,

```
public LoginPage(string _pdfUri)
{
 this.PdfUri = _pdfUri;

 CheckSessionWithUri(_pdfUri); //it checks session and send pdf path to PDFshowPage.
}

public LoginPage()
{     

 CheckSession(); //it sends user to the HomePage if the user correctly login or the user has login before.
}
```

I want to control when the user shares a pdf to my app, The app must send him To PdfShowPage. Should we control this on App.xaml.cs or somewhere else ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could pass the `_pdfUri` to `App` class,then open `LoginPage` base on the `_pdfUri`. like:

```
protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.Platform.Init();
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);


        Share();           

    }

private void Share()
{
  //Some codes for share
   LoadApplication(new App(_pdfUri));
}
```

then

```
public App(string _pdfUri)
    {
        InitializeComponent();   
        if(path !=null){
           MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage(_pdfUri))
            {
                BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("008000"),
                BarTextColor = Color.FromHex("E8E8E8")
            };    
        }else{
           MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage())
            {
                BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("008000"),
                BarTextColor = Color.FromHex("E8E8E8")
            };     
        }

    }
```

Comment: Yes, actually it should be work. I have solved this problem after I opened this question. I added a class which has bool value, it saves the value and returns that value when I use the share method. 

Thanks for answer Leo!